# How to manually remove all traces of Neo4J

Tags: neo4j

To get around my original, unanswered question i posted a few months ago:[Neo4j wont open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44489215/neo4j-wont-open)
I want to remove all traces of Neo4J and see if this allows me to reinstall it. (The uninstaller was unusable in the same manner the installer was). Otherwise i guess i need to reset my OS.

Note, i have removed everything that appears in a standard "neo4j" windows search. I am more thinking about reg edit files or hidden settings that don't show up there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the list of what is installed (InCtrl5 is pretty old but still does the job) :

```
Installation Report: Neo4j Community Edition
Generated by InCtrl5, version 1.0.0.0
Install program: L:\software\neo4j-community_windows-x64_3_2_1.exe 
7/22/2017 4:12 PM

------------------------------------------------------------
Registry
********

Keys ignored: 0
---------------
    * (none)

Values added: 4
---------------
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ej-technologies\install4j\installations "allinstdirs8478-6373-2628-9929"
        Type: REG_SZ
        Data: M:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ej-technologies\install4j\installations "instdir8478-6373-2628-9929"
        Type: REG_SZ
        Data: M:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StartPage\NewShortcuts "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Neo4j Community Edition\Neo4j Community Edition.lnk"
        Type: REG_DWORD
        Data: 01, 00, 00, 00
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StartPage\NewShortcuts "C:\Users\tomgeudens\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Neo4j Community Edition\Neo4j Community Edition.lnk"
        Type: REG_DWORD
        Data: 01, 00, 00, 00

Values changed: xx
------------------
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ej-technologies\exe4j\pids "l:\software\neo4j-community_windows-x64_3_2_1.exe"
        Old type: REG_DWORD
        New type: REG_DWORD
        Old data: A0, 19, 00, 00
        New data: 50, 09, 00, 00
------------------------------------------------------------
Disk contents
*************

Drives tracked: 7
-----------------
    * c:\
    * d:\
    * g:\
    * l:\
    * m:\
    * n:\
    * x:\

Folders added: 7
----------------
    c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Neo4j Community Edition
    c:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Neo4j Community Edition
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\.install4j
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\bin
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\bin\tools
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\plugins

Files added: xx
---------------
    c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Neo4j Community Edition\Neo4j Community Edition Uninstaller.lnk
        Date: 7/22/2017 4:10 PM
        Size: 561 bytes
    c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Neo4j Community Edition\Neo4j Community Edition.lnk
        Date: 7/22/2017 4:10 PM
        Size: 646 bytes
    c:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Neo4j Community Edition\Neo4j Community Edition Uninstaller.lnk
        Date: 7/22/2017 4:10 PM
        Size: 561 bytes
    c:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Neo4j Community Edition\Neo4j Community Edition.lnk
        Date: 7/22/2017 4:10 PM
        Size: 646 bytes
    c:\Users\tomgeudens\AppData\Local\Temp\i4j_nlog_15.log
        Date: 7/22/2017 4:10 PM
        Size: 9.711 bytes
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\LICENSE.txt
        Date: 5/31/2017 9:31 PM
        Size: 36.006 bytes
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\LICENSES.txt
        Date: 5/31/2017 9:31 PM
        Size: 150.060 bytes
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\NOTICE.txt
        Date: 5/31/2017 9:31 PM
        Size: 5.771 bytes
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\uninstall.exe
        Date: 5/31/2017 9:31 PM
        Size: 399.720 bytes
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\.install4j\autoUninstall.1
        Date: 7/22/2017 4:10 PM
        Size: 182 bytes
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\.install4j\files.log
        Date: 7/22/2017 4:10 PM
        Size: 3.230 bytes
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\.install4j\i4j_extf_0_kq51w0.utf8
        Date: 7/22/2017 4:10 PM
        Size: 33.540 bytes
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\.install4j\i4j_extf_1_kq51w0.utf8
        Date: 7/22/2017 4:10 PM
        Size: 2.648 bytes
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\.install4j\i4j_extf_2_kq51w0_16j209h.png
        Date: 7/22/2017 4:10 PM
        Size: 15.877 bytes
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\.install4j\i4j_extf_3_kq51w0_mxwygr.png
        Date: 7/22/2017 4:10 PM
        Size: 21.989 bytes
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\.install4j\i4j_extf_4_kq51w0_115hvx1.png
        Date: 7/22/2017 4:10 PM
        Size: 48.880 bytes
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\.install4j\i4j_extf_5_kq51w0.txt
        Date: 7/22/2017 4:10 PM
        Size: 36.006 bytes
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\.install4j\i4jdel.exe
        Date: 5/31/2017 9:31 PM
        Size: 79.904 bytes
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\.install4j\i4jinst.dll
        Date: 5/31/2017 9:31 PM
        Size: 156.160 bytes
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\.install4j\i4jparams.conf
        Date: 7/22/2017 4:10 PM
        Size: 34.124 bytes
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\.install4j\i4jruntime.jar
        Date: 7/22/2017 4:10 PM
        Size: 1.945.565 bytes
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\.install4j\inst_jre.cfg
        Date: 7/22/2017 4:10 PM
        Size: 36 bytes
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\.install4j\install.prop
        Date: 7/22/2017 4:10 PM
        Size: 100 bytes
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\.install4j\installation.log
        Date: 7/22/2017 4:10 PM
        Size: 14.084 bytes
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\.install4j\installer.ico
        Date: 7/22/2017 4:10 PM
        Size: 138.631 bytes
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\.install4j\MessagesDefault
        Date: 7/22/2017 4:10 PM
        Size: 33.540 bytes
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\.install4j\response.varfile
        Date: 7/22/2017 4:10 PM
        Size: 409 bytes
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\.install4j\stats.properties
        Date: 7/22/2017 4:10 PM
        Size: 649 bytes
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\.install4j\user.jar
        Date: 7/22/2017 4:10 PM
        Size: 6.729 bytes
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\bin\cypher-shell.bat
        Date: 5/31/2017 9:31 PM
        Size: 2.394 bytes
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\bin\install.properties
        Date: 7/22/2017 4:10 PM
        Size: 109 bytes
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\bin\neo4j-ce.exe
        Date: 5/31/2017 9:31 PM
        Size: 398.696 bytes
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\bin\neo4j-community.vmoptions
        Date: 7/22/2017 4:10 PM
        Size: 262 bytes
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\bin\neo4j-desktop-3.2.1.jar
        Date: 5/31/2017 9:31 PM
        Size: 86.765.376 bytes
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\bin\tools\2.x-config-migrator.jar
        Date: 5/31/2017 9:31 PM
        Size: 33.035 bytes
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\bin\tools\cypher-shell-all.jar
        Date: 5/31/2017 9:31 PM
        Size: 804.291 bytes
    m:\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\plugins\README.txt
        Date: 5/31/2017 9:31 PM
        Size: 271 bytes
------------------------------------------------------------
INI file
********

Ini files tracked: 2
--------------------
    * c:\windows\system.ini
    * c:\windows\win.ini
------------------------------------------------------------
Text file
*********

Text files tracked: 0
---------------------
    * (none)
------------------------------------------------------------
    InCtrl5, Copyright © 2000 by Ziff Davis Media, Inc.
    Written by Neil J. Rubenking
    First published in PC Magazine, December 5, 2000.
```

If you actually ran Neo4j too, there's two more directories created and used (these are the defaults) :

```
C:\Users\<youruser>\AppData\Roaming\Neo4j Community Edition\
C:\Users\<youruser>\Documents\Neo4j\
```

But seriously, **use the zip-installation**. You'll have the full toolset (instead of a subset) and you'll be able to control what goes where. Also, if something does go wrong on your system, you'll be able to determine the cause a lot quicker.

Hope this helps !

Regards,
Tom

Comment: Still cannot install it via the .exe but your note on using the zip is a great work around.